# Python count number of data in array list from response.json

Tags: python, json

I am trying to count the amount of users inside an array of data (see below). As you can see I can successfully obtain the data from response.json. So basically I am able to print the DATA but I am finding it hard to come up with a code to count the amount of users inside that data, I know the amount of users are 5 but I want to when I add an extra user that count will increment automatically.

Code:

```
    '''
    security service tests
    '''
    import sys
    sys.path.append('..')
    import requests
    import json
    from common.constants import *
    from config.settings import environment


    security_environment = environment()['security_service']
    service_url = "%s://%s:%d" % (
        security_environment['protocol'], 
        security_environment['host'], 
        security_environment['port'])


    def test1():
      print "TEST 1 - get user details"


      headers     = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
      url         = "%s/users" % service_url
      response    = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
      status_code = response.status_code


      print "STATUS: %s" % status_code
      print "DATA:   %s" % response.json()

      return status_code == HTTP_OK

     if __name__ == "__main__":
     num_pass = 0
     num_fail = 0

    for test in [test1]:
    print "-----------------------------------------------------------"

    if test():
      num_pass += 1
      print "PASS"
    else:
      num_fail += 1
      print "FAIL"

  print "==========================================================="
  print "%d passed, %d failed" % (num_pass, num_fail)
```

Result:

```
TEST 1 - get user details
STATUS: 200
DATA:   [{u'status': u'enabled', u'created_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'id': 1, u'updated_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'name': u'bart'}, {u'status': u'disabled', u'created_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'id': 2, u'updated_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'name': u'lisa'}, {u'status': u'enabled', u'created_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'id': 3, u'updated_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'name': u'homer'}, {u'status': u'disabled', u'created_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'id': 4, u'updated_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'name': u'marge'}, {u'status': u'enabled', u'created_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'id': 5, u'updated_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'name': u'maggie'}]
PASS
===========================================================
1 passed, 0 failed
```

Any Help?

Comment: You just save the data `data = response.json()` and append a new user dictionary `data.append(user)` (You need to have the user dict first.) To get the number of items in the list, just run `len(data)`.

Comment: and if you try this print len(response.json())  ?

Comment: Yeah your answer is right too, the way it worked for me was that i used data=response.json() then i just used the other guy's answer print(len(data)) and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list contains only users, than the most straight-forward solution is to use the **len()** function.

This code outputs 5:

```
data = [{u'status': u'enabled', u'created_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'id': 1, u'updated_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'name': u'bart'}, 
    {u'status': u'disabled', u'created_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'id': 2, u'updated_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'name': u'lisa'}, 
    {u'status': u'enabled', u'created_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'id': 3, u'updated_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'name': u'homer'},
    {u'status': u'disabled', u'created_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'id': 4, u'updated_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'name': u'marge'}, 
    {u'status': u'enabled', u'created_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'id': 5, u'updated_at': u'2016-02-09 10:49:28', u'name': u'maggie'}]

print(len(data))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked. can you see the way it says data = and then it shows all the users, i want to be able to show ''number of users='' and then it will show number of users

Comment: You could just simply add `str = 'Number of users = {0}'.format(len(data))`, than in the next line `print(str)`. This will print "Number of users = 5" in your case. (Hope I understand well what you meant)